# How can I click a link using it's HTML with Watir

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, watir

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/data_entry/ajax_add_term/131?contract_id=227', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); return false;">add a term</a>
```

I would like to click it using `contract_id=227`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser.link(:html, /contract_id=227/).click
```

Sources:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/wtr-general%40rubyforge.org/msg06838.html
- http://zeljkofilipin.com/2007/02/01/watir-select-element-using-html/